# Android Development Find Contact

Tags: android, contacts

so if I have a string of the name of the contact the user entered, how can I find the contacts information? I want to do this all in code, no GUI and not ContactPicker. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See: [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) – is there anything specific you've already tried?

Comment: No I haven't looked into but everything I could find kept using a picker.

Comment: That link was complicated lol. I thought implementing this would much easier.